# Mapping IList items to columns

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am working with a legacy database that has a table to store up to 5 categories a user has permissions to view:

```
USER_ELIGIBILITY
----------------
Eligibility_Id INT PRIMARY KEY
Eligibility_Name NVARCHAR(100)
CategoryId1 INT
CategoryId2 INT
CategoryId3 INT
CategoryId4 INT
CategoryId5 INT
```

The following is how I have created the class:

```
public Eligibility : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> AllowedCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the right way to model this? If so, how can I map it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something very similar with `<dynamic-component>`, only instead of `IList<T>` you need to map an `IDictionary`. See http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-dynamic.

Of course you can write a trivial wrapper to ignore the keys and focus only in the values from calling code.

Comment: See also: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/11/nhibernate-mapping-ltdynamic-componentgt.aspx